# How to determine when a SQL Subscription was marked for re-initialization?

Tags: sql-server-2012, transactional-replication

MS SQL Server 2012

I am trying to determine when a subscription was marked for reinitialization. I can see when the subscription started to reinitialize, but I want to see at what time the command was issued to reinitialize the subscriptions.

I have looked in the syssubscriptions table, there is a timestamp column, but that is not actually a time. Any way to determine in the sql logs or a modified datetime somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp refers to the date and time that the subscription was created.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested and you can get it from subscription_time value in your distribution database metadata like so:

```
select publisher_db, subscriber_db, subscription_time, *
from distribution.dbo.MSsubscriptions
where subscriber_id >=0
```

-Chuck